# Having problems to substract a variable from $end_date in #bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to substract the variable $i from the $end_date variable - any advice?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

COUNT="5"

declare -a arrWANTEDBACKUPS;
for ((i = 0 ; i < $COUNT ; i++)); do
    WANTEDBACKUPNAME=`date '+%Y%m%d_%H00' -d "$end_date-$i hours"`;
    arrWANTEDBACKUPS=(${arrWANTEDBACKUPS[@]} "$WANTEDBACKUPNAME");
    echo "$arrWANTEDBACKUPS[$i]";
    echo "Test";
done
```

Comment: shellcheck.net you mean, i cannot edit a comment.

Comment: Paste your script at shellcheck.net and fix the issues it reports. Also: `'+%Y%m%d_%H00'` will produce a format unsuitable for date input.

Comment: What is `$end_date`?

Comment: if `WANTEDBACKUPNAME` is also an array, then `WANTEDBACKUPNAME=(\`date '+%Y%m%d_%H00' -d "$end_date-$i hours"\`);` is needed. (you are treating it as a normal variable) And with `echo "${arrWANTEDBACKUPS[$i]}";`

Answer (score 0):

To do math with bash you need double round brackets, like in this example:

```
echo "$(($end_date-$i)) hours"
4 hours
```

So this works for me:

```
date '+%Y%m%d_%H00' -d "$(($end_date-$i)) hours"
20200901_1900
```

Comment: The date command will perform date time arithmetic if it recognize the date format. Shell arithmetic expressions are ok for very simple computation, then you'd prefer to work on Unix timestamps `'%s'` format expressed in seconds. Example: `hours=5;ts=$(date +%s); new_ts=$((ts-(3600*hours))); new_date=$(date -d "@$new_ts")`

Comment: Inside `((...))` you don't need the `$`'s.  It still works, but the `$`'s are not required in math contexts such as this or an array index.

Answer (score 0):

@Léa Gris & @TheSlater

Thanks - got it!

Here my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT="5"

declare -a arrWANTEDBACKUPS;
for ((i = 0 ; i < COUNT ; i++)); do
    WANTEDBACKUPNAME=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H00' -d "-$i hours");
    arrWANTEDBACKUPS=(${arrWANTEDBACKUPS[@]} "$WANTEDBACKUPNAME");
    echo "${arrWANTEDBACKUPS[$i]}";
    echo "$WANTEDBACKUPNAME";
    echo "Test";
done
```

Comment: You have not set `end_date` and (fortunately in this case) "$end_date" is an empty string. I think you mean `-d "$i hours"`.